# Calculus Problem from IMC $1994$

Tags: calculus, contest-math

> Let $f\in C^1[a,b]$, $f(a)=0$ and suppose that $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $\lambda >0$, is such that
>   $$|f'(x)|\leq \lambda |f(x)|$$for all $x\in [a,b]$. Is it true that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$?

*Solution:*
Say there exits an interval $[c,d]$ where funtion $f(x)$ is non zero so $|f(x)|$ is differentiable in $[c,d]$ with  $f(c)=0$. Now consider the function $g(x)=e^{-\lambda x}|f(x)|$ and see that $g'(x)\leq 0$. So $g $ is decreasing. So, $x\geq a \implies g (x)\leq g(a)=0$. Hence, $|f (x)|\leq 0\implies f (x)=0$

Is this solution correct? basically i am asking is the differentiablity of $|f(x)|$ makes sense

Comment: its given f is differentiable and taking f is non zero in (c,d], I think this should be enough for |f| to be differentiable

Comment: Are you assuming that $|f'(x)|=\left(|f(x)|\right)'$?

Comment: yes kinda as f is non zero in the given interval so I think we can do that, I am not sure though

Comment: Have you thought about the case $f(x)=-x^2$ at $x=-1$?